# How to get kubernetes pods or deployment IP to be used inside application

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-compose, dockerfile

I just tried setting up kubernetes on my bare server,

Previously I had successfully create my docker compose

There are several apps :

- Apps A (docker image name : a-service)
- Apps B (docker image name : b-service)

Inside Application A and B there are configs (actually there are apps A,B,C,D,etc lots of em)

The config file is something like this

```
IPFORSERVICEA=http://a-service:port-number/path/to/something
IPFORSERVICEB=http://b-service:port-number/path/to/something
```

At least above config work in docker compose (the config is inside app level, which require to access another apps). Is there any chance for me to access another Kubernetes Service from another service ? As I am planning to create 1 app inside 1 deployment, and 1 service for each deployment.

Something like:

```
App -> Deployment -> Service(i.e: NodePort,ClusterIP)
```

Thanks !

Comment: Is there any chance for me to access another Kubernetes Service from another service? You definitely can reach one service from another, moreover you can declare something located elsewhere as external service and use it inside of the Kubernetes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any chance for me to access another Kubernetes Service from
>   another service ?

Yes, you just need to specify DNS name of service (`type: ClusterIP` works fine for this) you need to connect to as:

```
<service_name>.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local
```

In this case such domain name will be correctly resolved into internal IP address of the service you need to connect to using built-in DNS.

For example:

```
nginx-service.web.svc.cluster.local
```

where `nginx-service` - name of your service and `web` - is apps's namespace, so service yml definition can look like:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx-service
  namespace: web
spec:
  ports:
  - name: http
    protocol: TCP
    port: 80
  selector:
    app: nginx
  type: ClusterIP
```

See [official docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/#services) to get more information.

Comment: how do I define the namespace ? should I create a namespace object after service layer and before deployment layer ? without namespace its just working fine (tested using dummy .yaml), it must have some sort of default namespace I suppose ?

Comment: @thegexploit you can create your pods/deployments/... in default namespace and specify `default` word there instead of `<namespace>`. but the best practice is to create your own namespace https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/namespaces-walkthrough/#create-new-namespaces before creating deployment for your app. So the flow is: `create namespace` -> `create deployment in that namespace` -> `create service to expose this deployment using ClusterIP`

Comment: @Artsion Praneuski so lets say my apps requiring to access service b at the apps.properties, I will just need to put `IP = http://b-service.default.svc.cluster.local/accessBService` , will it not ?

Comment: @thegexploit if you find my post helpful - please mark it as an answer. thanks

Comment: @Artsion Praneuski actually I dont think your solution is working, I even tried pinging other service by kubectl exec and sh to a pod, and try pinging another by using address, doesnt seem to be working, I use kubectl taint nodes --all node-role.kubernetes.io/master- though as I only have 1 machine currently, will it affect ?

Comment: @thegexploit I'm not sure ping should be considered as a reliable checker if another pod is accessible. Can you put pods into the same namespace, create service (ClusterIP) for at least one of them and then try to connect to exposed port from another pod using telnet for example?

Answer (score 1):

Use Kubernetes [service discovery](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#discovering-services).

> Service discovery is the process of figuring out how to connect to a
>   service. While there is a service discovery option based on
>   environment variables available, the DNS-based service discovery is
>   preferable. Note that DNS is a cluster add-on so make sure your
>   Kubernetes distribution provides for one or install it yourself.

[Service dicovery by example](http://kubernetesbyexample.com/sd/)